# Issue while deleting a list using CSOM in a SharePoint App

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

I am having this weird issue while deleting a list using CSOM. My SharePoint App has 2 buttons - one to create a list and the other to delete the created list.

When the app loads for the first time, list is created & deleted successfully. 
[image]
[image]

**When trying to delete the list again once its created, delete operation fails.**
[image]

On list deletion - 
[image]

Clicking Create button shows that the list does exist.
[image]

CSOM code to delete the list -

```
function listDeletion() {

    var list = null;
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    context.load(web);
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Tasks");

    list.deleteObject();  
    context.load(list);

    context.executeQueryAsync(success, fail);

    function success() {
        var mess = $("#message");
        mess.text("Tasks List deleted successfully");
     }

    function fail(sender,args) {
        var mess = $("#message");
        mess.text("An error occured : "+args.get_message());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.requestexecutor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext', listDeletion);
});

function listDeletion() {
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    this.list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Task");
    list.deleteObject();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function success() {
    var result = 'Task deleted.';
    alert(result);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

Comment: No. It didn't work. There was an exception - Object doesn't support property or method 'ExecuteQuery'

Comment: Edited, try now

Comment: This is also not working. Gave an exception -JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference.
I tried Function.createDelegate(this,success), but facing the same issue i posted.

Comment: Edited again. That code is working on my environment

Comment: Thanks for help but this also didn't work.The mentioned scripts are already included. SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext', listDeletion) will delete the list for the first as the function is called automatically. But when deleting the second time, it gives the same error.